# Return time from a NTP server signed by its RSA private key

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, ntp

As one part of an assignment application, I need to contact a NTP server and return the GMT time after having it digitally signed by the server's private key.
The getting the time part is easy.
I am coding in Java and using the apache.commons.net.ntp package of classes.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

My code template looks like this:

```
String TIME_SERVER = "ntp.server";   
NTPUDPClient timeClient = new NTPUDPClient();
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(TIME_SERVER);
TimeInfo timeInfo = timeClient.getTime(inetAddress);
long returnTime = timeInfo.getMessage().getTransmitTimeStamp().getTime();
Date time = new Date(returnTime);
```

I can't seem to figure out now how to request the server to sign the data first. My application can tolerate a small delay in the time sent. 
How to do this? Or should I not be using ntp classes if I intend to get digitally signed time?